# Flink standalonejob -restoreMode

Tags: apache-flink

I'm launching a Flink application cluster with the command

```
./bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --job-classname my.job.App-s s3://storage/savepoint-000000-a46bfd06daf8
```

Everything works fine. Job Manager starts and resume from provided savepoint (`-s` argument).
Now I'm reading about [savepoint restore mode](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/ops/state/savepoints/#restore-mode). I would set CLAIM mode in order give to Flink the ownership of the savepoint directory.
I tried to launch the Job Manager adding `-restoreMode CLAIM` argument to `standalone-job.s`h command:

```
./bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --job-classname my.job.App-s s3://storage/savepoint-000000-a46bfd06daf8 -restoreMode CLAIM
```

but this time I get this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils   [] - Could not parse command line arguments [--configDir, /home/ubuntu/dev/flink/flink-1.15.0/conf, -D, jobmanager.memory.off-heap.size=134217728b, -D, jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min=201326592b, -D, jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size=268435456b, -D, jobmanager.memory.heap.size=1073741824b, -D, jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max=201326592b, --job-classname, my.job.App, -s, s3://flink-storage/savepoint-000000-a46bfd06daf8, -restoreMode, CLAIM].
    
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.FlinkParseException: Failed to parse '--webui-port' option
```

If I pass `--restoreMode CLAIM`, Job Manager starts but seems to have no effect.
Documentation shows the `flink run` command

```
bin/flink run -s :savepointPath -restoreMode :mode -n [:runArgs]
```

Really -restoreMode works only launching a Flink application with `flink run command`?
How to achieve the same result using `standalong-job` command?

Answer (score 1):

try to submit like this:
`./bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --job-classname my.job.App-s s3://storage/savepoint-000000-a46bfd06daf8 -Dexecution.savepoint-restore-mode=CLIAM`

Comment: Adding `-Dexecution.savepoint-restore-mode=CLAIM` does not work. From webui jobmanager config still has the config:
`execution.savepoint-restore-mode NO_CLAIM`